# Check if a parameter contains variable or string

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How I can check if a parameter contains variable or string? For example :

```
    String text = "hello";

    //I want like this
    Demo(text);
    //But if he wrote like this give him error
    Demo("hello");

    public void Demo(String text) {

    }
```

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do that.  The language is designed at a very deep level so that those two versions are exactly equivalent.

Comment: I have an idea but I can't find a solution for this , there is no way never?

Comment: Nope.  You could pass a mutable holder object, which I suspect would be more what you want, but that's as close as you can get.

Comment: No, there is no way. What would be the point of that? Strings are immutable anyway, so if you want to modify the argument, it won't work.

Comment: okay , thank you <3

Comment: I think it might be possible with reflection. But then you enter a very dark world were the smallest mistake can cause a world of hurt. But why do you want this?